# Get property of class from an instance of subclass

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

As far as I know, the `__proto__` property of a constructor is considered deprecated. Is there a better way to access a property of the parent class from a created instance of its subclass?

**Example:**

In the following example, the requested property is `cls`.

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var cls = this.constructor.__proto__.cls + " " + this.constructor.cls;
    div.setAttribute("class", cls);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {}

Vehicle.cls = "vehicle";
Car.cls = "car";
Motorcycle.cls = "motorcycle";

let vehicle = new Vehicle();
let car = new Car();
let bike = new Motorcycle();
```

```css
.vehicle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.car {
  background-color: green;
}

.motorcycle {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf()` ? But why do you need to access the super class? If you are doing this a method, you can just use `super`. I don't think the code that works with an *instance* of a class should make any assumptions about its implementation.

Comment: It's related to obtaining the appropriate CSS classes for my styles to take effect @FelixKling. I've updated the snippet to illustrate my goal clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use static methods and `super`:

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var cls = new.target.getCls();
    div.setAttribute("class", cls);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
  
  static getCls() {
    return 'vehicle';
  }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
  static getCls() {
    return 'car ' + super.getCls();
  }
}
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
  static getCls() {
    return 'motorcycle ' + super.getCls();
  }
}

let vehicle = new Vehicle();
let car = new Car();
let bike = new Motorcycle();
```

```css
.vehicle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.car {
  background-color: green;
}

.motorcycle {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This allows sub classes to determine themselves how they want to build the class list.

If you always want to add the CSS class of the base class, why not access it directly?

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var cls = Vehicle.cls + " " + new.target.cls;
    div.setAttribute("class", cls);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {}

Vehicle.cls = "vehicle";
Car.cls = "car";
Motorcycle.cls = "motorcycle";

let vehicle = new Vehicle();
let car = new Car();
let bike = new Motorcycle();
```

```css
.vehicle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.car {
  background-color: green;
}

.motorcycle {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Felix. I needed this `__proto__` out of my code 